# Xdebug validation issues with PhpStorm and WSL2

Tags: magento, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

I'm trying to add Xdebug to my Magento project for better debugging. I'm actually working on WSL2, where I have installed Laradock.

If I try to display `xdebug_info()` I can see I have properly installed Xdebug, but in my PhpStorm I can not validate/stop on breakpoints etc.

This is my Xdebug configuration:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,gcstats,profile,trace
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
;# For PhpStorm set below to 9000 (or update IDE's settings).
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
;xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
```

And all my settings in PhpStorm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried installing different Xdebug versions, also made a lot of changes in xdebug.ini. I was also trying running PhpStorm inside in my WSL (I'm workings this way), but also I tried run it from Windows but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PhpStorm **inside** WSL, you need to use `xdebug.client_host=localhost`.

If it's in Windows, You should set `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway`.

If you use Laradock (docker) in WSL, then you need to use `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://nameserver`. `host.docker.internal` is for the network gateway, which doesn't link back to your WSL host.

There is a big list at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-NzNtExf5C4eOu3rRQm1WlWnbW44u3ANDDA49d3FD4/edit for multiple other scenarios.

Comment: I tried all configuration from your file, but still not working, when PhpStorm create validation file, after 1 sec that file is removed is that normal?

Comment: @dandan *"when PhpStorm create validation file, after 1 sec that file is removed is that normal?"* Yes -- PhpStorm uploads the file to your server, tries to execute it (via an URL) and then delete. If it does not execute -- check your web server access logs -- what URL it tries to access/maybe it's 404 error etc. In this case -- properly configure your web server  or deployment in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I actually found the issue, my nginx server was blocking file that PhpStorm was creating, now validation is working fine, but breakpoints are not working :/

Comment: @dandan Then show your current setup -- what Xdebug log has to say. I would also suggest to delete that "PHP | Server" entry and let PhpStorm create a new one -- maybe you have made some mistake there (e.g. wrong host name etc etc.) Maybe we can sop something that it off from that new info.

Comment: After delete it is working!! Thanks a lot ;) i spend all weekend trying to make it's works ;) I'll buy you a beer if we meet ;)